# How I can create sequence file in hadoop with API?

Tags: hadoop, sequencefile

I want create sequence file form array list of files address with haddop's API in one machine. Then give this output to `sparse-vector` and then `clustering`. For do sparse and clustering, I get code from [here](https://github.com/tdunning/MiA/tree/master/src/main/java/mia/clustering/ch09). `ReutersToSparseVectors` and `KMeansClustering`.
In [here](http://srijiths.wordpress.com/2011/02/23/sequence-files-in-hadoop/) is code for write sequence file. But, when I give sequence output to sparse, program give error.

Comment: The code there should work for any file system for which Hadoop has an implementation.  The URI determines which file system to use.  Make sure the URI says "file:///path/to/file.seq" and it will use the local filesystem instead of HDFS.

Comment: So, why there exist different for structure sequence file, between this code and command base?

Comment: Where is a different structure? A sequence file is still a sequence file, it is just a matter where it is stored.

Comment: Because, when enter this generation(sequence file) to input address for `sparse vectors` operation, this program give me error. What do you means about `where it is stored` in your comment?

Comment: Unless, text file isn't input for creating sequence.

Comment: What error does the sparse vectors program give, exactly?  That would clear up a lot.

Comment: I forgot tell you that I give array list for input sequence(I edit my question). It's error is that cannot access to input file.

Comment: Do you think that union array list file into one file, can a way for solve this problem? And after K-means clustering operation, can I understand number of clustering of every file?